Texlive and beamer on Fedora 40 gives error
While compiling the following file content:
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{hello}
\end{document}

pdflatex gives an error:
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@ifregister #1#2->\pgfutil@IfUndefined 
                                               {pgfmath@if#1@extract}{\errme...
l.73 \pgfmath@ensureregister{dimen}{\pgf@x}

Please help. Fedora 40 + texlive

Can you show your .log file so we can see which version of texlive and beamer you have?

https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~caklovic/TeX/test.log

Here it is. Sorry.

Can you try without local files like /home/lax/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty? They might contain an old version of the package.

My mistake. This style remained present locally even after the upgrade of Fedora. Than you for the HELP. :)

You're welcome! Have fun with beamer and fedora :)

I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by comments.
